# Using AppleScriptObjC to read content file and write new content to it

Tags: xcode, applescript, applescript-objc

I want to write an applescript code that reads a file and writes back to it when I modify input dialog

**like** :

```
set theFile to "/private/etc/hosts"
set theFileContent to read theFile
```

I created a text field and 2 buttons using Xcode 4.6 . I want to use the above code to read content of the hosts file and show it on a textfield, and when i modify the text field and click save button, it should write back to hosts file with admin permission. I tried but they dont work for me, maybe i dont know the difference between applescript and applescriptobjc.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set theFile to ("your/Path/...")
set theFileHandle to open for access theFile write permission true
write "someText" to theFileHandle
close access theFileHandle
```